# Prove the solution to this ODE is genuine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=\dfrac {x(1+e^y)}{e^y(1+x^2)}$$
I believe I have the correct solution
$$y=\ln ({C\sqrt {1+x^2}-1})$$
to the ODE shown but can't seem to prove the solution is genuine when substituting back into the original equation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jx4S.jpg)

Comment: Why are you asking this question? You have a proposed solution to the ODE. You know how to check it. What is the purpose of this post?

Comment: The purpose of the post was to ask how to show the solution was genuine. I could not manipulate the solution into the original equation to show it was correct. See the answers below for what I was after. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\ln ({C\sqrt {1+x^2}-1})$$
$$e^y={C\sqrt {1+x^2}-1}$$
Differentiate:
$$e^yy'=\dfrac {Cx}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}$$
Now the DE is:
$$e^yy'=\dfrac {x(1+e^y)}{(1+x^2)}$$
$$\dfrac {Cx}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}=\dfrac {x(1+e^y)}{(1+x^2)}$$
$$C=\dfrac {(1+e^y)}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}$$
$$C=\dfrac {C(\sqrt {1+x^2})}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}$$
$$C=C$$
Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $y = \ln(C\sqrt{1+x^2} - 1)$, then $e^y = C\sqrt{1+x^2} - 1$. Now we verify whether this solution is correct:
$$\begin{align} \textrm{LHS} &= y'\\&= \frac{d}{dx} \ln(C\sqrt{1+x^2} - 1)\\&=\frac{1}{C\sqrt{1+x^2} - 1}\times\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\times 2Cx\\ &= \frac{1}{e^y}\times \frac{Cx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\times \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\&= \frac{x}{e^y} \times\frac{C\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}\\&=\frac{x}{e^y}\times\frac{e^y+1}{1+x^2} \\&= \textrm{RHS}\end{align}$$
Thus the solution you found satisfies the ODE.